# Jquery animate finish triggers half way animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have a card layout that looks like this: https://image.prntscr.com/image/AOyf0PwmQDWtJwqf_r4ckA.png

With the help of this code I going to extend the card when I press "Show Details" but I can't seem to change the time the animation runs OR sync the finished function to when it's actually done. It triggers halfway of the way the height animation has happen.. what am I doing wrong?

Here is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                    var block;
                    var pTag;
                    $(".showFullCard").click(function () {
                        block = $(this).parents(".roadmap-block");
                        $(this).toggle(function () {
                            $(block).animate({
                                height: "400px"
                            }, 200);
                            $(block).css({ "position": "relative", "z-index": "1" })
                        }, function () {
                            $(block).animate({
                                height: "700px"
                            }, 200);
                            $(block).css({ "position": "absolute", "z-index": "2" })
                        });
                    });
                    $(document).click(function (event) {
                        if (!$(event.target).closest(block).length) {
                            $(block).animate({
                                height: "400px"
                            }, 200, function(){
                                $(block).css({ "position": "relative", "z-index": "1" })
                            });

                        }
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add the HTML markup so we can test the code.

one option that might be easier is to create a CSS class with transition and toggle that class using :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("showFullCard").click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('yourClass');
   });
});
```

CSS:

```
.yourClass {

height:600px!important;
width:200px;
padding 100px;
transition:  all .5s ease;

}
.roadmap-block{

width:400px;
height:400px;
background:#ccc;
padding:20px;
transition: all .3s ease;

}
```